# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I get this error on Chrome:

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL1 from frame with URL2

I searched for this but most places there is actually an Iframe used and it tries to access parent.

In my case, I do not have an IFrame, but get this error. It is on page:

http://sikhvideos.org/video-details.asp?id=39

To get the error on Chrome, you click on one of the video clip thumbnails below the main video screen. This results in the content on the Right of Video to be populated. This is done by replacing the content inside the id "width366px".

The code for that is the usual:

```
document.getElementById("width366px").innerHTML= <data returned by ajaxVideoPartDetails.asp>
```

All help very much appreciated.

Best Regards
sandy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because the script is running from `static.ak.fbcdn.net` and even if the main site runs on the same url that the video is come from, the script is not.

So chrome is check the script and the script is run from a different site and this raise this error.

The solution is to move this part of the script on the page - or on your domain and call it from there and not from the other site.